# finding index values of multiple Objects that share data field values in an ArrayList

Tags: search, indexing

I have an ArrayList storing cars (for instance). Each instance of a car has three data fields (make, model, and year). Make and Model are both Strings, and year is an Int value. I want to be able to search the ArrayList and return the index location of every car that was produced in 2014 (say). I can use a simple search to return the first index location using something like this:

```
  public static int searchYear(ArrayList<Cars> cars, int key)
 {
     int size = cars.size();
     for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
     {
        if (cars.get(i).getYear() == key)      
            return i;       
     }
     return - 1;
 }
```

where key == 2014 (the year I am searching for). How can I get this to return the index value of all cars with that key rather than only the first instance of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: you shall return an array of values, instead of a single `int`. Like in this signature:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> searchYear (ArrayList<Cars> cars, int key)
```

More comments:

It is misleading that your parameter is named `key` if there is more than one instance that matches that key. The key is not an unique key, but just a value... I'd call that parameter `year` instead.

The signature of your method shall be something like this:

```
public static int[] searchYear (Cars[] cars, int year)
```

Of course you shall implement in your method the creation of an array of ints, appending the indexes those cars that match your year parameter.

You may ask yourself why I changed `ArrayList<Cars>` by `Cars[]`. Well, it is a matter of flexibility of future uses of this method you are creating. A plain array [] is a more common construction that `ArrayList`. Actually I would not put `ArrayList` in my method signature unless I'm using any method specific of `ArrayList`.

Since you are accessing by index with .[get](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get-int-)(i), this method is defined at the [`java.util.List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface, so a `List` argument makes sense:

```
public static int[] searchYear (List<Cars> cars, int year)
```

We can talk about the `int[]` return type: another option would be a `Collection<Integer>` or even `Iterable<Integer>`. The reasoning to choose one or another would be the same as for the `cars` argument: it all depends on what you want to do with the list of indexes returned by your method.